# auto find and replace in Google Docs App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps

I'm trying to create a note-taking template/script for Google Docs (docs, not spreadsheets) that automatically converts abbreviations into full words/phrases (ex. typing 'mgmt' automatically turns into 'management'). I can't figure out how have this happen in real-time (vs. running the script after typing is done, which would basically be a quicker find and replace).

Any tips? Or is this even possible? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Have you actually tried anything yourself yet? What things have you already thought about?

Answer (score 0):

If you look under "Tools" and click "Preferences", that would be what you are looking for.

Cheers.