# Replacing words in Google Docs with Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am looking to create a macro that takes a certain set of characters, and replaces it with another set of characters. This would preferably occur while I'm typing. How would one go about writing this in Google AppScript?

Also, I do realize that this question is very similar to this one: [auto find and replace in Google Docs App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973630/auto-find-and-replace-in-google-docs-app-script?rq=1), but I would like it to be able to replace the set when it's within another word.

Comment: Related: [How to find and remove blank paragraphs in a Google Document with Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39962369/1595451)

Comment: Thank you for the link @Rubén, but that is concerned with removing blank paragraphs rather than swapping out characters.

Comment: That Q&A could serve you to start writing a script to do what you are looking for. Currently this question is too broad. While a link to a similar question is included, questions should be self-contained, meaning the question should not force readers to look into another question to understand what is being  asked. By the other hand the referred question hasn't a good answer and it isn't a good question (no upvotes).

Comment: @Rubén I added the link to the other question as to state how my question was different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Real-time text replacement is problematic because it requires a way to automatically detect changes to the document. While spreadsheets support the `onEdit` trigger, docs do not. You can simulate this behavior, as demonstrated [in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773177/how-to-poll-a-google-doc-from-an-add-on/24773178#24773178)

If real-time replacement is not a requirement, you can simply write a function to do a regex replacement, and add the function to the menu:

```
function replaceText(){
  var docBody = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  docBody.replaceText('[Aa]pple','pear'); 
  //Will replace "apple", "Apple," "applesauce", "pineapple"
}

function onOpen(e){
  DocumentApp.getUi()
  .createMenu("Text Replacer")
  .addItem("Replace all Text", 'replaceText')
  .addToUi();
}
```

For help writing your regex, [see this document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417?hl=en).